# IntelliJ Spring Boot project can't find my CSS files with Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new to Spring Boot and my problem is that I have Spring Boot project and I am intending to view my HTML pages with Thymeleaf but Spring can't resolve my JavaScript and CSS files.

*Full picture of my IDE:*
[image: Full picture of my IDE]

Those are my Thymeleaf configurations

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=true
```

This is my HTML page head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       >
<head>
    <title>404 Page</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <!-- Css Files Start -->
    <link href="/src/main/resources/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/><!-- All css -->
    <link href="/src/main/resources/static/css/bs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/><!-- Bootstrap Css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/src/main/resources/static/css/main-slider.css" media="screen"/><!-- Main Slider Css -->
    <!--[if lte IE 10]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/customIE.css" media="screen"/><![endif]-->
    <link href="/src/main/resources/static/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/><!-- Font Awesome Css -->
    <link href="/src/main/resources/static/css/font-awesome-ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/><!-- Font Awesome iE7 Css -->
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/noJS.css"/>
    </noscript>
    <!-- Css Files End -->
</head>
```

Comment: What are the errors you get if you check the console view? It generally helps to include the errors. In this case, I'd guess that the pathing might be incorrect - but without the actual output you're getting, that's hard to verify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use relative path to your JavaScript and CSS files:

```
<link href="../../static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

or you can use `th:href` Thymeleaf's tag as well:

```
<link th:href="@{css/style.css}" href="../../static/css/style.css"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found that Spring automatically searches for: `/resources/`.
So what I did was removed all the pre-directories by using find all.

So, in my case what used to be for example: `/static/css/style.css` & `/templates/index.html`

became: `/css/style.css` & `/index.html`

Now the question remains how does Spring boot know what folder to look in without you defining it: Spring looks at the extension. When spring boot sees `.html`, it looks for it in a folder called `/templates`.