# Spring Boot Thymeleaf doesnt load static files

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Im having the same problem as mentioned here: [Spring Boot Thymeleaf static content doesn´t load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726626/spring-boot-thymeleaf-static-content-doesn%C2%B4t-load)

My project Structure is the same as follow.

But my scene is:

Im getting 404 error looking the console, like:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/dist/css/meuestilo.css
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
```

From Spring console, i get:

```
2017-02-15 23:44:23.160  WARN 8260 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/dist/css/meuestilo.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

My link tag is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dist/css/meuestilo.css" th:href="@{/dist/css/meuestilo.css}" />
```

What is wrong?

The template was created following this tutorial: http://blog.codeleak.pl/2013/11/thymeleaf-template-layouts-in-spring.html

Before changes, it works perfectly!

Comment: try to use `th:href="@{/css/meuestilo.css}"` reference instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution using:

```
layout:decorator
```

As mentioned here [Thymeleaf Layout Documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html)

Answer (score 0):

As referring to your first link i believe that your meuestilo.css should be inside static/dist/css/meuestilo.css
So your link tag should be like this,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/css/meuestilo.css">
```