# Linking CSS to HTML view using Thymeleaf

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

Good morning, good evening, good night,

A noob question here, i'm using Thymeleaf as a template engine, and linking Bootstrap CSS sheet doesn't seem to work, here is my strucuture

resources
-static
--css
---bootstrap.min.css
-templates
--view.html

and line of code

`< link rel="stylsheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{../css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>`

Edited: I do get the plaintext .css file when i open the link in the href,
        And  the `.table-striped` attribute i'm using in my table class does exist in the CSS file.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
```

Thank you for your feedback

Comment: When you go into the developer tools (F12), what error do you see?
I don't know Thymeleaf, but I think you should use ../static/css/bootstrap.min.css.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your feedback, i don't see any errors on the dev console, i just tested the link by opening it and i do get the plaintext .css file .. i guess that means that the path is correct, but i still can't see the css look and feel on the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ Spring Boot project can't find my CSS files with Thymeleaf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40452365/intellij-spring-boot-project-cant-find-my-css-files-with-thymeleaf)

Comment: i have already tried the dynamic path as mentioned there, that's not it.. the path is recognized and links to the css file, any idea why its still showing a simple html table without css ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it finally .. it was the URLs, this is what worked for me, 
**/static** is handled by default i guess so removed it from the url and its "twerkin".

**Structure**
-static
--css
---bootstrap.min.css
-templates
--view.html

**CSS Link**
th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun way to check if your paths are right! I'll use Chrome as my example, but maybe your browser of choice does it slightly differently.

1. Open the developer tools
2. Find your link
3. Right click on the URL in the href and click "Open in new tab"

You'll either see a plaintext .css file, or you'll get a 404. If it's a 404, your path is wrong!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your feedback, Surprisingly enough i do get the plaintext .css file when i open the link, and attribute i'm using in the class does exist but weirdly the page still has no CSS

Comment: It's likely a silly problem then - check your selectors, check for typos, check everything relevant. Better yet, if you can reproduce it in a codepen or jsfiddle, we could help you better still.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add scripts to the head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your feedback Alisa, i don't think that adding the scripts in necessary for linking a CSS resource to an html view though, yes, no ?